# Win10 Tools 1.1 x86 package marked as arm in dev center

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I upgraded to  VS Win10 Tools 1.1. When I now build an app, first I had to change the option create bundle to never since there where errors when I would upload the bundle. Now it generates me a separat appxupload for each platform. When I upload all three I get an error that two of them has the same platform. I noticed then that the x86 package targets the arm platform instead of the x86, even though I selected Release (x86) on build. 
When I remove the x86 package again I can submit the other two to the store. It will pass certification and be published.

How can this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my fault. I changed accidently the Platform taget in the build settings for release. That was the reason why it worked on my pc (since I always use debug), but not on build.